# Which pictureBox was selected onClick? C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am working on a image viewer and have encountered a small problem.

I load the images into the program using a dialog box then put them into individual picture boxes.

I do not know how to do the onclick for each picture box as when its clicked I want that image to display in a bigger picture box.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp";
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach(String fileName in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                images.Add(new Bitmap(fileName));
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                Image loadedImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pb.Width = flowLayoutPanel1.Width;
                pb.Height = 200;
                pb.Image = loadedImage;
                pb.MouseClick += pb_MouseClick;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
                pb.Name = "" + x;
                x++;
            }
        } 
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} images loaded",images.Count),"",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void pb_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // handle click event
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            MessageBox.Show("Image clicked");

        pbMain.Image = images[0];
        pbMain.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If, in your Click handler for the picture boxes, cast `sender` to a `PictureBox` like so:

```
PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
```

Then you don't need to know which one specifically was clicked.  Just use that reference to grab the image and put it in the larger box.